# Codeigniter under IIS - SOAP "Method not allowed"

Tags: codeigniter, iis, soap

I have a very simple CodeIngiter code in a controller to call a WebService exposed on a .NET application. Both Codeigniter and the .NET applications run under IIS / Windows.

The issue I have is that I get a "Method not allowed" when I try to call a method from that Web Service.

Here is my controller in CodeIgniter

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class TestWS extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
        $client = new SoapClient(
            "https://localhost/myWebApp/services/MyWebServices.Samples.asmx?wsdl",
            array(
                "trace" => 1,
                "location" => "https://localhost/",
                'exceptions' => 1,
                "stream_context" => stream_context_create(
                    array(
                        'ssl' => array(
                            'verify_peer'       => false,
                            'verify_peer_name'  => false,
                        )
                    )
                )
            ) 
        );
        $client->GetSamples_sessionless(null, null, "myuser", "mypassword");
        var_dump($client);
        
        
    }
}
```

and what I get is

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: SoapFault

Message: Method Not Allowed
```

I can also browse to the WSDL and see it properly

Code crashes in the GetSamples (whether sessionless or not with this issue).
This may be an IIS permission, not sure
What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: make sure you enabled  enable HTTP Activation: Go to Control Panel > Windows Features > .NET Framework 4.5 Advanced Services > WCF Services > HTTP Activation. try to pass login info like this `$client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl", array('login'          => "some_name",
                                            'password'       => "some_password"));` try to access HTTP instead of https. refer this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276389/wcf-over-https-with-php-throws-method-not-allowed-exception

Comment: I did everything you suggested, meaning
1) HTTP Activation and NonHTTP Activation (they weren't turned on) - still same method not allowed
2) called client passing credentials in login - still same method not allowed
3) attempted with HTTP instead of HTTPS - not working in my case

Comment: are you using a self-signed certificate? also, try to remove the  WebDAV module from iis `<modules>
            <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
        </modules>`